# Creating a graph showing mapping from origins to ends in a specific format?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Apologies if I have not framed my question properly.

I am trying to create graph showing mapping from `origins` list to `ends` list. I am unable to get the required structure.
I tried all kinds of GraphLayout options but none of them worked for my case.
Can someone please point me to how to go about this?

**Sample code:**

```
ends = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
origins = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
mps = UndirectedEdge @@@ Tuples[{origins, ends}];
Graph[mps, VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]

**Expectation:**

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
vlist = Join[ends[[{2, 1}]], Reverse @ origins, ends[[{4, 3}]]];

g = Graph[vlist,
 mps, 
 GraphStyle -> "NameLabeled", 
 GraphLayout -> {"MultipartiteEmbedding", "VertexPartition" -> {2, 9, 2}}]
```

[image]

**Update:** Modify the coordinates of first two and last two vertices:

```
vc = MapAt[4 # &, GraphEmbedding[g], Thread[{{1, 2, -1, -2}, 2}]];

Graph[g, VertexCoordinates -> vc]
```

[image]

Replace `4 # &` with `8 # &` to get

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Exactly what I was looking for. Is there anyway to increase space between vertices? for example between `a` and `b`?

Comment: @AnjanKumar, please see the update.

Comment: Thank you for the update.

Answer (score 10):

You can specify the [`VertexCoordinates`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexCoordinates.html)

```
$Version

(* "13.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (November 18, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

ends = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
origins = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
mps = UndirectedEdge @@@ Tuples[{origins, ends}];

g = Graph[mps,
  VertexLabels -> Placed[Automatic, Center],
  VertexCoordinates -> {{0, 4},
    {-2, 1}, {-2, -1}, {2, 1}, {2, -1},
    Sequence @@ Thread[{0, Range[3, -4, -1]}]},
  VertexStyle -> White,
  VertexSize -> .5]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for showing how to space the vertices.